# Getting an error while installing Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am getting this error in command line, please help

```
C:\Users\admin>npm -v
6.9.0

C:\Users\admin>npm install  -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...vkit/core":"8.0.4","r'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-13T09_21_07_788Z-debug.log

C:\Users\admin>node -v
v10.16.3

C:\Users\admin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following steps. Make sure you have installed node.js in your computer.

```
  npm cache clean --force
  npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: thanks! it's resolved.